# Show that $\Omega(0)=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

For each $r\geq0$, let $\Omega(r):C((-\infty,0])\rightarrow C((-\infty,0])$ be a map defined by $\Omega(r)(x(t))=x(t-r)$ for $t\leq0$. How can I prove that $\Omega (0)=I\ $?

My attempt: If $r=0 \Rightarrow\Omega(0)(x(t))=x(t)$. I could note that $\Omega^n(0)(x(t))=\Omega(0)(\Omega(0)\circ...\circ\Omega(0)(x(t)))=...=\Omega(0)\left ( \Omega(0)(x(t)) \right )=\Omega(0)(x(t))=x(t)$, ie $\Omega^n(0)(x(t))=x(t),\ n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is that correct? Can someone help me to continue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm sorry but your proof is nonsense.

The chief problem here is that you have misplaced parentheses.  $\Omega(r)$ has the following action on each $x$:

$$(\Omega(r)x)(t)=x(t-r)$$

It is an $r$-shift operator.  If $r=0$, the shift is null.  In symbols:

$$(\Omega(0)x)(t)=x(t-0)=x(t)$$

In other words, $\Omega(0)x$ is just $x$ itself.

There is not much here to prove.

Comment: No. The expression "$\Omega(r)(t)\cdot x(t)$" is itself nonsense.  Each $\Omega(r)$ is an operator. Call it $T$. and each $T$ sends a function $x$ to a different function $y$.  The function $y$ is defined by $y(t)=x(t-r)$.  Since $Tx=y$, we have $(Tx)(t)=x(t-r)$. And since $T=\Omega(r)$, we have $(\Omega(r)x)(t)=x(t-r)$.